# How to select data and store the result in a variable

Tags: c#

I am trying to select data from MS database and store the result in a variable.

I want to use default visual studio commands without a framework.

Firstly I am doing an insert statement, then i want to retrieve the scope_identity().

```
SqlCommand recipe_insert_command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO RecipeTbl (USER_ID,RECIPE_DESC) VALUES ('" + user_id + "','" + recipe_desc + "');", con);
recipe_insert_command.ExecuteNonQuery();




SqlCommand getRecipeID_command = new SqlCommand("SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();", con);
getRecipeID_command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The insert works. What about the select?

Comment: Use `ExecuteScalar` which will return the result. If selecting multiple rows you can use `ExecuteReader`

Comment: okay so `getRecipeID_command.ExecuteScalar();` then how i store it in a variable?

Comment: That is the very wrong way to create a SQL query - it is very prone to syntax, data mismatch and other errors as well as sql injection problems when deployed.  Find a good NET database tutorial to learn the right way before continuing

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp that is not the answer though. I know it's not the best way but it's not wrong

Comment: @VasilisMitas did you try to insert a value for your Recipe_Desc that contains a single quote? The way you do it is wrong from the start.

Comment: It is very, very wrong.  It has never been the correct way with the NET framework.

Comment: You can store it. But you have to select with specific detail like `Select SCOPE_IDENTITY Where Name = .... And ID = ....`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i suggest to display to datagridview like this. Sorry for writing in MySQL but it is almost similar to SQL.

```
string conn = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=;CharSet=utf8mb4;";  
string query = "SELECT * FROM RecipeTbl;"

MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(conn);
MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connection);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds, "RecipeTbl");
datagridview1.DataSource = ds.Tables["RecipeTbl"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware of [sql injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Use [parameterized](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8) queries.

Always free the resources used: [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

```
string sql =
    "INSERT INTO RecipeTbl (USER_ID, RECIPE_DESC) VALUES (@user_id, @recipe_desc);" +
    "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";

using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var recipeCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
{
    con.Open();

    recipeCommand.Parameters.Add("user_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = user_id;
    recipeCommand.Parameters.Add("recipe_desc", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = recipe_desc;

    var id = (decimal)recipeCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    Console.WriteLine(id);
}
```

Of course, specify the data types that are used in your table: [SqlDbType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqldbtype?view=netframework-4.8).